# Simple Content Switching with JQuery and CSS

Tags: jquery, html

I have several divs of class wrap. Each has several divs of class content. How can I automatically switch out the content that is showing using jquery and css?

```
    <div class="wrap">
    <div class="content is-showing"></div>
    <div class="content is-not-showing"></div>
    ...
    </div>

<div class="wrap">
<div class="content is-not-showing"></div>
<div class="content is-showing"></div>
...
</div>    

...
```

Comment: What do you mean by "switch out the content"?

Comment: I'm with @j08691 on this one. I started to answer and it's not clear exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you want something like this?:

http://jsfiddle.net/Btcue/

CSS:

```
.is-not-showing {

  display: none;

}
```

JS:

```
$( ".wrap > .content" ).toggleClass( "is-not-showing" );
```

Answer (score 0):

How bout simply:

```
$('.is-not-showing').hide()
function switch() {
    $('.is-not-showing, .is-showing').toggle();
}
```